# Filtering hit-hat beat from an audio with FFT

Tags: c++, audio, filter, fft, frequency-analysis

So i am writing a beat detection algorithm, and it works cool, but it detects every beat (drum, voice, hi-hat, etc.).
And I am trying to take only a hi-hat beat sound.
Here is part of the code, where i am using FFT and trying to filter it:

```
            for (int channel = 0; channel < numChannels; ++channel) {
                for (int j = k * smallbuf_samples; j < (k + 1) * smallbuf_samples; ++j) {
                    smallbuffer[channel].push_back(bigbuffer[channel][j]);
                }
            }
            fftw_complex x[smallbuf_samples];
            fftw_complex y[smallbuf_samples];
            for (int i = 0; i < smallbuf_samples; ++i) {
                x[i][REAL] = smallbuffer[0][i];
                x[i][IMAG] = smallbuffer[1][i];
            }
            fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(smallbuf_samples, x, y, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
            fftw_execute(plan);
            fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
            fftw_cleanup();
            std::vector<double> b;
            for (int i = 80; i < smallbuf_samples; ++i) {
                y[i][REAL] = 0;
                y[i][IMAG] = 0;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < smallbuf_samples; ++i) {
                b.push_back(y[i][REAL] * y[i][REAL] + y[i][IMAG] * y[i][IMAG]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < smallbuf_samples / very_smallbuf_samples; ++i) {
                double sum = 0;
                int j;
                for (j = i*(i+1)/2 * 108/13 + 22/13; j < (i+1)*(i+2)/2 * 108/13 + 22/13 && j < smallbuf_samples; ++j) {
                    sum += b[j];
                }
                Es[k].push_back((float) (j - (i*(i+1)/2 * 108/13 + 22/13)) / (float) smallbuf_samples * sum);
            }
            for (int channel = 0; channel < numChannels; ++channel) {
                smallbuffer[channel].clear();
            }
```

So, as you can see, i am filtering it by setting all the y samples index higher than 80 to 0 (because the frequency of hi-hat is around 300..3000 Hz).
Although, my beat algorithm detects voice, drums and other beats.
How to fix it and what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd approach it differently. What you do now is you filter frequencies in an audible range, but you should filter then in an inaudible range, where the beat range lines. I.e. not "give me frequencies less than 300 Hz (less than 300 cycles per second)", but "filter the frequencies between 40 cycles **per minute** to, say, 200 cycles **per minute**, which is **from 0.6 Hz to 3.3 Hz**
But you can't analyze the audible signal for that. You need to create an inaudible "peaks" signal first:

- go through the signal and take peaks only, build the second signal (it will be inaudible, because the frequency is too low and even if you could hear it - it won't make any sense to your ear)
- analyze the resulting signal with FFT, set up for lower frequency range (say, 128 times slower than your 20-20000 you use to analyze audible signal, so you have 0.15-150 Hz result)
- filter it to 0.6 to 3 Hz
- and find the loudest peak in this range (or the lowest - here you'll need to experiment). This will be your beat. Multiply it by 60 to convert Hz to BPM

Of course, the window for your FFT must be much slower than an audible signal, here it must be:

- at least 2 seconds to detect frequencies above 0.5 Hz
- a size must be big to increase the resolution in lower frequencies

With this approach it doesn't really matter what exactly makes the beat: it could be a bass drum, just a base guitar or piano, i.e. the frequency of the beat making instrument doesn't matter (with your approach, where you filter high frequencies, songs with "only hi-hat" won't be detected

Comment: I am creating a "only hi-hat" audiofile from origin audiofile, so i need to know what exactly makes the beat. Also i didnt understand, what are we doing in your algorithm of analyzing a non audible signal. Why do we need to do that if "hi-hat" is audible?

Comment: 0..80 interval is 0..3000 Hz interval in my case(44100 Hz sampling frequency), where hi-hat frequency lies